# Confused on how php objects handle arrays

Tags: php

The output of this is "24", when I'd expect "44".

```
class some_class {
    public $array = array();

    public function construct() {
        $this->array[5] = 4;
    }

    public function something() {
        // $this->array at this point is empty, why?
        echo (isset($this->array[5])) ? $this->array[5] : 2;
        $this->array[5] = 4;
        // Here, $this->array holds the value 4 in the key 5 correctly
        echo (isset($this->array[5])) ? $this->array[5] : 2;
    }
}

$some_object = new some_class();
$some_object->something();
```

Any ideas why my expectations are being shattered?

Comment: `public function construct()` should be `public function __construct()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your constructor isn't firing it needs to be called:

```
public function __construct(){
 // constructor
}
```

otherwise the array fails to initialize.

Answer (score 4):

Your question basically boils down to your line at the beginning of `something()`, asking:

> $this->array at this point is empty, why?

This is the case because PHP constructors need to be named [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), whereas yours is simply named `construct`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `construct()` is never called. You should name it `__construct()`.